# .Jar file runs well from NeBeans but not from /dist lib

Tags: image, pdf, netbeans, javafx, window

I am a bit new at Java and Netbeans but I've heard that you are a great and helpful community, so could you give me an advice how is it possible that a source code (after compiled) works fine if I hit the green triangle in NetBeans, but if I open the contain of the **DIST**/jar file (outside from NetBeans) it is not?

More precisely the application runs well but one specific function doesn't run when I click a button (PDF generation with iText plugin).

Here is a part of code of the not working method (as I mentioned **the button works, but only if I start my App from NetBeans**)

If I remove the image reference, the Application runs well from outside (total commander, /dist/myapp.jar, Enter), but I really would like to use the image in the PDF file. The path is good (since it is working from netbeans)

So I am 100% sure that the .jar does not find the logo (if it works without it,) but then how could it find if it is started from NetBeans? What could I rewrite at the path? (I tried "/", "@", "/src" while the .png can be found at /src just like the other pictures (which are loaded perfectly) )

```
 public void pdfGenerate(String title, String text) {

  ............................
        document.open();
        Image image1 = Image.getInstance("src/logo.png");
        image1.scaleToFit(200, 86);
        image1.setAbsolutePosition(200f, 750f);
        document.add(image1);

        document.add(new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n\n" + text, FontFactory.getFont("font", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();
  ...............................
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you package your application as a jar file, the resources should be packaged there too. The [method you are calling](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)) interprets the string as a filename; that file will not be present on the system when the jar file is created and deployed.

What you need to do is specify a URL for the resource. You can do this using `getClass().getResource(...)`. If you specify a resource path here starting `/`, it will be interpreted relative to the classpath; otherwise it is relative to the current class.

Note that there is an [overloaded form of `Image.getInstance(...)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance(java.net.URL)) taking a URL.

So, it looks like you need

```
Image image1 = Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("/logo.png"));
```

You can also check the contents of the jar file from the command line with

```
jar -tf yourfile.jar
```

to make sure the image file is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to specify relative path from the jar-file to your image?
Your src-folder is packed into the jar, but you are trying to get external file (image).

Check if src-folder still located in the same folder with jar. 
If it doesn't exist try to create it manually and place image there.

Comment: I see. In this case could you tell me how to modify my code to reach the "inside" picture which is packed in to the .jar file? Because the whole package will be sent to another computer, and needs to be able to run alone.

Comment: Yes he did, but thank you too for pointing at the problem! ;)